# Drawing a POLYGON from initial position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My problem is: I need to draw with mode POLYGON with a initial point, like a marker or another element. For example - [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b8vd96ce/2)

With marker:

`var initialPosition = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: {
        lat: -22.397542,
        lng: -46.884630
    }
});`

This position is given without any user interaction. How can I  do that?
In my example, how can I draw a polygon starting from marker without click it, making marker position my first polygon point?

Comment: So you want to basically programmatically set the first point of the polygon then have the draw mode as active? so as the user clicks on the map the next point will be added?

Comment: You probably don't need the `DrawingManager`, just create an editable Polygon on the first map click.

Comment: loan.burguer, exactly, I want that the next user click create the first segment from marker to click position.

Comment: geocodezip, can you provide an example of editable Polygon? I searched here and found [resizeable polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/user-editable-shapes), but cant change the number of segments. I need allow the user draws the polygon as it wish.

Comment: ^^ That's not a Polygon. That's a Rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following: use `addListenerOnce` to detect a click on the map (only once). This will allow to create a Polygon that goes from your marker position, to where the user clicked, and back to the marker position.

By setting the `editable` property to `true`, you can then move each Polygon point separately, and add segments by dragging the existing segment(s) middle point(s).

Here is a working example:

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2, 6.17);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(e) {

    var origin = marker.getPosition();
    var coords = [
      origin,
      e.latLng,
      origin,
    ];

    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      map: map,
      paths: coords,
      editable: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is not the answer I expected, but its my fault. My question wasn't specific. The user can draw the polygon with or without an initial point, without initial point I'm using DrawingManager, with initial point I need something similar to drawing mode, for reasons of user experience. But you gave me an idea with addListenerOnce, I updated my code to do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/b8vd96ce/11/). I will mark your answer as correct, because my question wasn't specific and you answered the problem of question.